# remove some character of a string in C

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings

I have been trying to remove some characters from string (one is at a specific position, the other is at the end), but no success. I have read many posts on stack**overflow** on this as this is a popular question which has been answered already I think like this: [Removing last character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949552/removing-last-character-in-c)

But so far I have no success:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // I just want a string of oliverb@hotmail.com in the end
    // so I performed all the steps below:

    const char c = '<';
    char *ret = strchr("FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>", c);
    char *stripFrontBac = ret;
    
    printf("value of ret %s\n", stripFrontBac);
 
    // this part here removes the Front of the current string stripFrontBac
    stripFrontBac++;
    printf("value of ret %s\n", stripFrontBac);
    
    // here I tried to remove the last character like
    // how it was done in the attached link. But
    // error must have happened in this line. Since
    // when I step into the following in a debugger, it says "seg fault"
    stripFrontBac[strlen(stripFrontBac) - 1] = '\0';
    
    // this line still has the symbol > in the end of the string
    printf("value of ret %ld\n", strlen(stripFrontBac));
}
```

could someone tell me what I might have done wrong?

I have actually tried using a debugger, it says there is a `seg fault`.

Comment: Modifying string literals yields undefined behaviour, you can't do that. Do `char input[] = "FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>";` and then `char *ret = strchr(input, c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a major problem in the code:

- you are trying to modify a string literal: this has undefined behavior, likely a `segmentation fault`.
- you should instead determine the start and end of the string fragment you want to extract and allocate a new string from this fragment with `strndup()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *extract_email(const char *str) {
    const char *start = strchr(str, '<');
    if (start == NULL)
        return NULL;
    start++; // skip the '<'
    const char *end = strchr(start, '>');
    if (end == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return strndup(start, end - start);
}

int main(void) {
    // I just want a string of oliverb@hotmail.com in the end
    // so I performed all the steps below:
    const char *str = "FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>";
    char *email = extract_email(str);
    if (email) {
        printf("email is: %s\n", ret);
    } else {
        printf("no email in: %s\n", str);
    }
    free(email);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hello, in your function extract_email, is the argument being email or it is str? because str doesn't seem to appear anywhere inside the function. Sorry is the name of the argument correct? thank you

Comment: @john_w: sorry about that, the argument is `str` and used as an argument for the first  call to `strchr`.

Answer (score 0):

OP's key problem is trying to modify a *string literal*, which is *undefined behavior* (UB).

**Use a modifiable string**

```
// char *ret = strchr("FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>", c);
char source[] = "FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>";
char *ret = strchr(source, c);
```

**Or only print the characters between `<` and the end**

```
cost char *source = "FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>";
const char *begin = strchr(source, c);
if (begin) {
  source = begin + 1;
}
size_t len = strlen(source);
if (len > 0) {
  len--;
}
printf("%.s\n", (int) len, source);
printf("Value of ret %zu\n", end - begin);
```

Comment: this is a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

OP's key problem is tiring to modify a *string l iteral*, which is *undefined behavior* (UB).

**Use a modifiable string**

```
// char *ret = strchr("FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>", c);
char source[] = "FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>";
char *ret = strchr(source, c);
...
```

**Only print the characters between `<` and the end**

```
cost char *source = "FROM:<oliverb@hotmail.com>";
const char *begin = strchr(source, c);
if (begin) {
  source = begin + 1;
}
size_t len = strlen(begin);
if (len > 0) {
  len--;
}
printf("%.s\n", (int) len, source);
printf("Value of ret %zu\n", len);
```